# Why was FDR so determined for the US to join WWII?

Tags: world-war-two, fdr

I have read an FDR biography and it goes into great details about FDR's difficulties in convincing a largely isolationist population, a reluctant military and an almost hostile Dept of State to support the Allies in WWII. It did not go into why. Was his motivation moral, personal or geopolitical? I know he was a political pragmatist but this was one issue that did not look like a vote winner before Pearl Harbor.

P.S. Call me cynical but I do not think any politician's public speeches are a good indication of what he/she really thinks. I consider private conversations and letters or even the opinions of people who know them well to be much better sources.

Comment: We have looked at this issue before: [Why was Franklin D. Roosevelt pro-intervention?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/33906/16951)

Comment: Thanks. That link has the answer: "Wilsonian ideology"